# Initializing part of a multidimensional array with a list of constants in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

Say I have an array

```
int A[2][2];
```

and I want to initialize only the first row with a list of constants like so

```
A[0] = {
    1,
    2
};
```

**Unfortunately the compiler returns.**

**error:**

```
expected expression before '{' token_.
```

Although this example is small, think big. I know there are some obtuse ways of doing it but it would shock me if there wasn't an efficient solution.

Comment: This is not initialization. Initialization would be `int A[2][2] = {{1,2}};`

Comment: You cannot **assign** an array to an array. And there is no partial _initialisation_ in C.

Comment: @EOF Isn't it though? Without assignment the array has garbage values so that would lead me to believe the first assignment no matter where is the array's initialization.

Comment: @Bob C11 draft standard n1570: *6.7 Declarations 6.7.9 Initialization* Initialization is part of declaration. You're trying to *assign* something.

Comment: @EOF Alright, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Questions about 2D arrays are easier to discuss and answers are more clear when the size of the dimensions differ.  IOWs, use `int A[3][2];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initializers do not work like that. You should initialize it at the time of declaration as

```
int A[2][2] = { {1, 2} };        // Rest elements will be initialized to 0
```

or using designated initializer

```
int A[2][2] = { [0] = {1, 2} };  // C99 and later
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is not *initializing* (which is done *only* when the variable is declared) but *assigning*.  An array is a non-modifiable lvalue, which means it has an address but can't be assigned to.

You can explicitly set just the first element as follows:

```
int A[2][2] = {{1, 2}};
```

When initializing an array or struct, any unspecified values in an initializer are set to 0.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't initializing; you're trying to assign, and you can't do array assignment in C.

To be initialization, it would be part of the variable definition:

```
int A[2][2] = { { 1, 2 } };
```

This initializes the first row of the matrix explicitly leaving the rest as zeros.